# props.string Cannot read property 'toString' of null or 'toLowerCase' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

Tengo un componente `DialogSlice` que recibe por `props` sus datos, entre sus `props` que recibe existe uno llamado `name` donde este es una cadena de texto (`string`).. Resulta que quiero transformar ese texto en minúsculas y use el método o función `toLowerCase()` para hacer esto, pero recibo el siguiente error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null

Pense que quizás no estaba recibiendo un `string` y trate de convertirlo a uno usando el método `toString()` pero desafortunadamente recibo el mismo `TypeError` que el anterior.

Dejo a continuación parte de mi código

```
<DialogSlide
    name={props.name}
/>
```

Intente de las siguientes formas, obteniendo siempre el mismo resultado.

```
<DialogSlide
    name={props.name.toLowerCase()}
/>


const name = props.name.toLowerCase()
<DialogSlide
    name={name}
/>
```

Cabe mencionar que `props.name` viene del `state` del componente padre de `DialogSlice`. ¿A que se debe el `TypeError` si el valor es un `string`, pero por que no lo reconoce como tal?

Comment: Tienes dos evidencias de que `props.name` no es string, para saber que es puedes hacer `console.log(typeof props.name)` y/o `console.log(props.name)`

Comment: Toda la razón !!! en el state como initial value estaba null...

Comment: Claro, para no tener estos problemas, conviene inicializar los valor según el tipo que van a tener, así por ejemplo `"".toLowerCase()` no nos arroja error.